# File.isDirectory() returns true and false for same Directory

Tags: java, windows, directory

`AUX` is a prohibited keyword in Windows for naming directories/files in Windows. I've written below Java code that creates this directory in two different ways, one using in-built `mkdir()` method and another using `exec()`.

The file object pointing to this same directory returns `true` and `false` respectively when `isDirectory()` is invoked. I would like to understand the reason behind this.

**Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

class Test{

    public static void main(final String... arguments) throws Exception{

        File file=new File("\\\\.\\\\.\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");

        file.mkdir();
        System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
        file.delete();

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c md \\\\.\\\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");
        System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rd \\\\.\\\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
C:\Temp>javac Test.java

C:\Temp>java Test
true
false
```

Comment: Try adding a `Thead.sleep();` statement after `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c md \\\\.\\\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");`, because there is a chance that the windows command processor needs a few seconds to boot up and carry out the command.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Process.waitFor(), you can insure that the directory has been created before you test if it exists

```
class Test{

    public static void main(final String... arguments) throws Exception{

        File file=new File("\\\\.\\\\.\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");

        file.mkdir();
        System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
        file.delete();

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c md \\\\.\\\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rd \\\\.\\\\C:\\Temp\\AUX");

    }

}
```

Comment: Rather "you will wait while cmd process finishes".